# Google Maps v3 and XML implementation approach

Tags: xml, google-maps, xpath

I would like some input on which of the following two approaches is more appropriate.

**1.** Should I load a "master" XML file then use XPath on it? With this solution I would only rewrite the "master" XML file when the site updates its local database.
-or-

**2.** Should I generate an XML file for each query and then load that specific file?  Then just do some cleanup every so often on all the XML files that would be generated.

NOTES:

- I am implementing this on a Realty site.
- This is kind of obvious, but still going to point it out, queries are formed from a search form that narrows down results based on user input.
- The site has a cron job that updates a local database from a remote
  database every so often.
- The "master" XML file would likely not have more that 600 properties.
- This site isn't super busy, about 100 to 150 visitors a day.
- I would be using JavaScript to load the XML and parse with XPath.

Answer (score 1):

First off i personally really like JSON and you should use it because it is lighter.
600 markers are really small number and i suggest to load them  all together once.
Maybe you can also use a marker manager such as [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/) (example) iff the results are overlapping each other.

So i suggest the first option as the multiple requests are unnecessary.

Comment: Are you going with option #1 then?  Or suggesting something different?  Could you please expand on your suggestion?  I am currently loading the XML with the example from a Google Maps V3 API article `downloadXML()`.  As for my first suggestion, I then build and XPath expression from the current form values and run that against the data object that `downloadXML()` returns.